# Compressing the output of a specific action in Symfony?

Tags: json, http, symfony1

I am writing an action that returns a JSON response. Due to the amount of data involved, I want to use HTTP compression for that action.

How do I specify HTTP compression for the output of a specific action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a symfony way to compress specific responses only. There's a couple of ways you could do it though:

- Your own filter that starts/stops the necessary output buffer compression depending on the route (have a look at the More With Symfony book for how filters work)
- Configure this on the webserver. With Apache, you can use a `LocationMatch` block to only compress responses that match the given URI. Nginx will let you do the same thing with a `location` block. I'm sure others (Varnish, lighttpd etc) will do too.

Unless you're experiencing some crazy traffic for very dynamic content, there's probably no reason not to enable compression at the webserver level.